# Big response time difference between result from JMeter and Postman

Tags: jmeter, postman

I saw a big difference regarding the API response time with 1 single user/request between JMeter and Postman.

Below is the config on JMeter:
[image]

The response time was around 8.5s:

[image]

However, the response time of the same API request was much faster on Postman:

[image]

I ran them from the same laptop and same network. Any idea what caused this big result discrepancy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first guess would be [Caching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching).

- Postman is a browser plugin so you're comparing JMeter which always creates a fresh session including establishing the connection with a browser which might [keep the connection open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Keep-Alive)
- You're not sending the same request at least when it comes to [Cache-Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) header
- If you want something to compare JMeter with - it should not be Postman, it should be a tool which establishes clean session each time, i.e. [cUrl](https://developer.ibm.com/articles/what-is-curl-command/)
- Even when you amend your JMeter script to behave exactly like Postman, comparing a single request is not something you should be doing, try running 10-100 iterations and compare average/median response times

By the way, in order to stop making assumptions you can just record your Postman request using JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder:

1. [Prepare JMeter for recording](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733979-Recording-a-user-session-with-the-proxy). Start HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder using the ["Recording" template](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#basic-instructions)

   [image]
2. Prepare Postman for recording. [Configure it to use JMeter as the proxy](https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/proxy/)

   [image]
3. If you're recording HTTPS traffic you will also need to [import JMeter's certificate into Postman](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/certificates/)

   [image]
4. Run your request in Postman. JMeter will capture it and generate relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager).